# Why does PHP's method_exists() CALL (!) a method when it should just return a boolean by definition?

Tags: php

### Problem

PHP's `method_exists()` [[doc page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php)] checks if a method exists and returns a boolean. BUT: Under special circumstances (when class and method have the same name) this function really CALLS a method. I'm really confused with this and have attached two reproduceable, copy&paste-ready examples to prove.

### Question

Seriously, WTF ? Is this a bug or intended behaviour ? Am I violating some code convention rules that cause this ?

### Code that reproduces the problem

Code & compiled result: http://viper-7.com/SFFRLL

```
<?php

class foo
{
    public function foo()
    {
        echo 'Method foo() in class foo was called !';
    }
}

$foo = new foo();
if (method_exists($foo, 'foo')) {
    // The line above already triggers the execution of foo();
}
```

### Code that (intentionally) does NOT reproduce the problem

Code & compiled result: http://viper-7.com/MPLe5M

```
<?php

class foo
{
    public function bar()
    {
        echo 'Method bar() in class foo was called !';
    }
}

$foo = new foo();
if (method_exists($foo, 'bar')) {
    // Nothing should happen
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Delete `method_exists` and the code will still exhibit the problem. That's because old style PHP 4 constructors are still supported, in which the constructor function is named after the class. `foo::foo` is the constructor and is called on `new foo`.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! PHP4 was LONG before my time, never even heard of that !

Comment: Hmm yes that's true, but reading method_exists() docs and everything directly related didn't even get me there. Imo this issue deserves a note in the `method_exists` docs.

Comment: It should have been a clue that *changing the name of the method* fixed the problem, without changing anything about `method_exists`... :P

Comment: @Panique The behavior has nothing to do with `method_exists()` so putting a note there doesn't make much sense.